# how to deploy Windows WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-7

I have a simple Windows Form application(WPF) with entity framework. After compiled, only a few files generated:

```
EntityFramework.dll
EntityFramework.xml
MyApp.exe
MyApp.application
MyApp.exe.config
...
```

Then I just copy following files to a network shared folder:

```
EntityFramework.dll
MyApp.exe
MyApp.exe.config
```

Then I can double click on MyApp.exe from developer computer the launch the app, but can not launch from another end user computer.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Windows Form application (WPF), I'm confused...

Comment: Make sure you have the proper .Net Framework version installed in the target computer.

Answer (score 0):

When you double click, app is not launching means certainly it is crashing so type the command eventvwr in run or cmd it'll open the Event viewer in that go to Windows Logs and Click on Application,  you can see different levels of logs in that just find the last error log view the details it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the event log on the target computer and look at the error that is actually being reported.

It could be a missing installation of the correct version of the DotNet framework as suggested in the comments above, or it could also be that the execution policy of the target computer is preventing the user from running from a network drive (As a developer you probably have admin rights on your local pc allowing you to do this).

Whatever the actual cause you are always better to use some form of installer, rather than this form of putting files on the network (commonly known as xcopy deployment).

Probably the best solution is to use Visual studio to generate you a click once installer and publish it to your network drive. This will then copy the application locally on the users pc and run it from there.